# Are there any simple/explicit examples of a finite vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

By finite vector space, I mean a non-trivial vector space with a finite number of elements, not just a finite field. I'm hoping for a really simple example, even better if that set is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2):

Any finite vector space is a vector space over a finite field. A down to earth example is the vector space of all $64$-bit binary numbers with XOR as addition, which is a vector space over the field with 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

How about the integers mod 2 over the field of integers mod 2?

Any finite field over itself as the field of scalars is a simple example of a finite vector space.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at vector spaces over graphs (note the space is defined for the specific graph). Cycle space over a specific graph $G$ takes the edge-disjoint cycles in $G$, with addition being the symmetric difference. The field is $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, so scalar multiplication is trivial. Cut-space takes edge-disjoint cuts rather than cycles, and is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ with the same operations. Both spaces are subspaces of edge space. A graph's vertex space is defined the same way. These vector spaces have nice properties relevant to graph theory, such as Mac Lane's planarity criterion, which states:

> > A 2-basis of G is a basis of C(G) with the property that, for each edge e in G, at most two basis vectors have nonzero coordinates in the position corresponding to e. Then, stated more formally, Mac Lane's characterization is that the planar graphs are exactly the graphs that have a 2-basis.

Cite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Lane%27s_planarity_criterion

You may also want to check out this article on graph vector spaces:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/328653-algebraic-graph-theory-vertex-and-edge-spaces/